# I'm getting a letter output instead of the index value printed twice, why is that?

Tags: python

```
names = ['Amir', 'Bear', 'Charlton', 'Daman']

print(names[-1][-1])
```

I'd expect it to print Daman twice but it's giving outputting the letter n instead??

Answer (score 1):

If you try

```
print(names[-1])
```

you'll see it prints

```
Daman
```

then `[-1]` again (1 from the right)

it prints

```
n
```

Comment: I got it now, it's printing index -1 but then index -1 for that word, new to python thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You get position -1 in the list which is 'Daman' and position -1 in 'Daman' which is 'N'.

do:

```
print(names[-1]*2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't indexing `names` twice; you are indexing `names`, then indexing whatever `names[-1]` evaluates to.

`names[-1] == 'Daman'`, and `'Daman'[-1] == 'n'`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain how Python actually interprets your code.

It looks like, in general, you want to start with a list of indices (such as -1,-1,3) and print out the corresponding elements of the array. To do that, you could do the following.

```
idx = [-1,-1,3]
print(*(names[i] for i in idx))
```

As expected, the result is

```
Daman Daman Bear
```

Answer (score 0):

You access the last item in the list and then the last letter.
If you want to print twice use a loop or just :

```
print(names[-1])
print(names[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using -1 index to print last list element

To access the last element of the list `names` you have to use only one couple of `[]`. Below I show the execution of your code with only a couple of `[]` directly in a Python shell:

```
>>> names = ['Amir', 'Bear', 'Charlton', 'Daman']
>>> print(names[-1])
Daman
```

As you can see the previous instruction prints `Daman`.

So with `[-1]` you access at the last element of the list; this element is the string `Daman`.
With the second `[-1]` you access at the last char of the string `"Daman"` that is the letter `n`.

### Execute print 2 times

To print 2 times the last element of list `names` you can execute the instruction `print(names[-1])` 2 times, or use the istruction `print(names[-1] * 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case priority is left to right. so names[-1] would return last element of list which is Daman and names[-1][-1] that is equal to "Daman"[-1] would return last char of string which is n.
there is multiple ways to print it twice and one solution could be:

```
print(names[-1], names[-1])
```

or you can use loops and etc.